# What is the benefit to having a header node and a trailer node in a linked list?

Tags: linked-list

I learned linked lists by having a pointer that points to the first node of the list. This pointer would be the head of the list. I assume if I wanted a trailer pointer then I could do the same thing with the last node in the list.

Now I have seen another implementation of the Linked List, where there is  a dummy node before the front of the list and a dummy node at the end of the list. I do not see why we need these dummy nodes.

Picture example [image]

Edit: added example to clarify question.

With the implementation below if I want to add to the front of the the list I would I not have to do this?

```
Node temp = A->next;
A->next = new Node();
A->next->next = temp;
```

Now with the first node marked as the head node instead

```
Node *newNode = new Node();
newNode->next = head;
head = newNode;
```

How is the above method more simplified?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dummy nodes in linked lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952882/dummy-nodes-in-linked-lists)

Answer (score 1):

Dummy node may be added before the first data record or after the last one to simplify and accelerate some list-handling algorithms, by ensuring that all links can be safely dereferenced and that every list (even one that contains no data elements) always has a "first" and "last" node. It is a kind of hack which is used to avoid edge cases.

`For Example` - In an insert function of a circular doubly linked list. you can create a dummy node that is beneficial and can eliminate special cases like when the list is empty.

For more Info. [Refer](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/faculty/boyland/classes-archive/fa15.cs351/www/linked-list-variations.html)